# Is `scipy.misc.comb` faster than an ad-hoc binomial computation?

Tags: python, math, scipy, combinations, combinatorics

**Is it conclusive that now the `scipy.misc.comb` is indeed faster than the ad-hoc implementation?**

According to an old answer, [Statistics: combinations in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025162/statistics-combinations-in-python/3025547#3025547), this homebrew function is faster than `scipy.misc.comb` when calculating combinations `nCr`:

```
def choose(n, k):
    """
    A fast way to calculate binomial coefficients by Andrew Dalke (contrib).
    """
    if 0 <= k <= n:
        ntok = 1
        ktok = 1
        for t in xrange(1, min(k, n - k) + 1):
            ntok *= n
            ktok *= t
            n -= 1
        return ntok // ktok
    else:
        return 0
```

But after running some tests on my own machine, this doesn't seem like the case, using this script:

```
from scipy.misc import comb
import random, time

def choose(n, k):
    """
    A fast way to calculate binomial coefficients by Andrew Dalke (contrib).
    """
    if 0 <= k <= n:
        ntok = 1
        ktok = 1
        for t in xrange(1, min(k, n - k) + 1):
            ntok *= n
            ktok *= t
            n -= 1
        return ntok // ktok
    else:
        return 0

def timing(f):
    def wrap(*args):
        time1 = time.time()
        ret = f(*args)
        time2 = time.time()
        print '%s function took %0.3f ms' % (f.__name__, (time2-time1)*1000.0)
        return ret
    return wrap

@timing
def test_func(combination_func, nk):
    for n,k in nk:
        combination_func(n, k)

nk = []
for _ in range(1000):
    n = int(random.random() * 10000)
    k = random.randint(0,n)
    nk.append((n,k))

test_func(comb, nk)
test_func(choose, nk)
```

I get the following output:

```
$ python test.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/misc/common.py:295: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in exp
  vals = exp(lgam(N+1) - lgam(N-k+1) - lgam(k+1))
999
test_func function took 32.869 ms
999
test_func function took 1859.125 ms

$ python test.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/misc/common.py:295: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in exp
  vals = exp(lgam(N+1) - lgam(N-k+1) - lgam(k+1))
999
test_func function took 32.265 ms
999
test_func function took 1878.550 ms
```

**Did the time profiling test show that the new `scipy.misc.comb` is faster than the ad-hoc `choose()` function?** Is there any error on my test script that makes the timing inaccurate?

**Why is it that the `scipy.misc.comb` is faster now? It is because of some `cython` / `c` wrapping tricks?**

---

## EDITED

After @WarrenWeckesser comment:

Using the default floating point approximation when using `scipy.misc.comb()`, the computation breaks because of floating point overflow.

(see http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.misc.comb.html for documentation)

When tested with `exact=True` which computes with long integers instead of floating point using the function below, it's a lot slower when computing 1000 combinations:

```
@timing
def test_func(combination_func, nk):
    for i, (n,k) in enumerate(nk):
        combination_func(n, k, exact=True)
```

[out]:

```
$ python test.py
test_func function took 3312.211 ms
test_func function took 1764.523 ms

$ python test.py
test_func function took 3320.198 ms
test_func function took 1782.280 ms
```

Comment: By default, scipy's `comb` computes a floating point value, which will be an approximation when the arguments are large enough.  You should compare the timing using the argument `exact=True` in `comb`.

Comment: Wow, after using `exact=True` it's uber slow. So is there any reason not to use the ad-hoc function instead of the `scipy.misc.comb`

Comment: Good question!  If you feel motivated, you could add any comments that seem relevant to https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/3449

Answer (score 1):

Referring to the source code of [scipy.misc.comb](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.16.1/scipy/special/basic.py#L1163), the update routine of the result is:

```
    val = 1
    for j in xrange(min(k, N-k)):
        val = (val*(N-j))//(j+1)
    return val
```

whereas the update routine you suggested is:

```
    ntok = 1
    ktok = 1
    for t in xrange(1, min(k, n - k) + 1):
        ntok *= n
        ktok *= t
        n -= 1
    return ntok // ktok
```

My guess of the reason why SciPy's implementation is slower is due to the fact that the subroutine involves an integer division at each iteration while yours only calls division once at the return statement.