# simulate binominal coefficent (nCr) in python

Tags: python, combinations, simulation

Out of curiosity, I was wondering if there's a way to solve a binominal coefficient by simulation in python. I tried a little bit, but the numbers are getting so big so quickly that I wasn't able to solve it for anything but really small numbers.

I'm aware of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025162/statistics-combinations-in-python) but wasn't able to identify one solution that uses only brute force to solve the coefficient. But I  have to admit that I don't understand all the implementations listed there.

Here's my naive approach:

```
import random
import numpy as np
from math import factorial as fac

# Calculating the reference with help of factorials

def comb(n,k):
    return fac(n) // fac(k) // fac(n-k)

# trying a simple simulation with help of random.sample

random.seed(42)
n,k = 30,3
n_sim = 100000
samples = np.empty([n_sim,k], dtype=int)


for i in range(n_sim):
    x = random.sample(range(n),k)
    samples[i] = sorted(x)

u = np.unique(samples, axis=0)

print(len(u))
print(comb(n,k))
```

Would it be possible to do this efficiently and fast for big numbers?

Comment: I don't get your code : 8 lines to built "u", which is not used...
plus : function comb as defined in your code is fast on my computer and can handle quite big numbers, even if it is quite a vague definition...

Answer (score 0):

I use this, its pretty efficient for large numbers:

```
def nck(n, k):
    if k < 0 or k > n:
        return 0
    if k == 0 or k == n:
        return 1
    k = min(k, n - k)  # take advantage of symmetry
    c = 1
    for i in range(k):
        c = c * (n - i) // (i + 1)
    return c
```

Comment: it may be magic, but using timeit, it shows to be two to three times slower than using `fac`

Comment: Not for big numbers it isnt.
try:
`nck(10**6,50*10**3)`
vs
`comb(10**6,50*10**3)`

(4s vs 46s on my computer)